# OSGi (Karaf) maven dependencies resolution

Tags: java, maven, osgi, apache-karaf

I am creating a new Karaf feature that would contain several bundles (jclouds). I also have a maven "superproject" (jclouds-all) that contains all the modules/bundles I need.

Is it possible, when defining the feature, to specify just the one superproject's bundle and have all the concrete bundles resolved automatically or do I need to list all the bundles in my feature?

I tried it:

```
<feature name="my-cloud" version="${project.osgi.version}" resolver="(obr)">
    <bundle start-level="${core.startlevel}" dependency="true">mvn:org.apache.jclouds/jclouds-all/1.6.2-incubating</bundle>
</feature>
```

and it complains:

*java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to build OBR representation for bundle mvn:org.apache.jclouds/jclouds-all/1.6.2-incubating*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bundle needs to be a single artifact. So you have to list all the maven modules or bundles within the feature element. You cannot get Karaf to resolve a maven super project into artifacts and download them.

Comment: Thanks, Kamal. I noticed there is a maven plugin that can inspect all required dependencies and generate a feature file from that. Unfortunately I'm havibg some problems with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793142/how-to-generate-karaf-features-descriptor