# How to generate a Karaf features descriptor

Tags: java, maven, osgi, maven-plugin, packaging

I am trying to automatically generate Apache Karaf's (2.3.0) feature desscriptor file (*features.xml*).

From [Karaf's doc](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/developers-guide/karaf-maven-plugin.html) I have learned that I can use the "features" packaging.

my *pom.xml*

```
<project>
...
    <packaging>feature</packaging>


    <dependencies>      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jclouds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jclouds-core</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
                <artifactId>karaf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${karaf.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <startLevel>80</startLevel>
                    <aggregateFeatures>true</aggregateFeatures>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

But `mvn clean install` complains:

> Unknown packaging: feature

I have also tried to use the `features-maven-plugin`, but I get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the `org.apache.karaf.tooling:karaf-maven-plugin:jar:2.3.0` does not exist in the maven repo.

I changed it to `3.0.0.RC1`, and now it works well. This solution is OK for Karaf 3.x.

For Karaf 2.x, the problem was really with the packaging. *pom* is fine with http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.x/developers-guide/features-maven-plugin-generate.html.

**BUT:** the `features-maven-plugin`'s `generate-features-xml` does not work at this time, the produced features file is "empty". See the [related issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KARAF-1681).

Comment: It would be really nice if you posted the working configuration for your POM !

Comment: [relevant documentation for karaf 4](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_features_and_kar_goals)